# Python: How to properly reassign attributes to work with parent class functions

Tags: python, inheritance

I am trying to create a parent class and a child class in Python. Ive created getter functions within the parent, that call the parent's attributes using self. When creating the child, I do not want to override the function, simply reassign the value. When I do this, and call the getter from the child, I still receive the parent's attribute value. How can I force the code to use the child's attribute without having to override the getter function?

My class definitions are as follows:

```py
class Dad:
    def __init__(self):
        self.likes = "Baseball"
        self.name = "John"

    def get_likes(self):
        print(self.likes)

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def works(self):
        print("Programmer")


class Son(Dad):
    def __init__(self):
        self.likes = "Soccer"
        super().__init__()

    def works(self):
        print("Student")
```

When trying to run the code,

```py
d = Dad()
s = Son()
d.get_name()
d.get_likes()
d.works()
s.get_name()
s.get_likes()
s.works()
```

the output looks like this:

```
John
Baseball
Programmer
John
Baseball
Student
```

My desired output would be:

```
John
Baseball
Programmer
John
Soccer
Student
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `Son` attributes to overwrite those of the parent class:

```
class Son(Dad):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.likes = "Soccer"
```

This is the canonical way to implement child precedence.

Comment: So the issue comes down to the line order between super()._init() and self.likes = “Soccer” ?

Comment: Right.  Each of those sets the `likes` attribute.  As with any other variable, the second one overwrites the first.